# What Icon is Appropriate For Sorted by Time?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, icons, ui-guidelines

I have a duplicate bridge scoring application with two different sorting modes.

Let me fill you in on how duplicate bridge works so you have an idea what I'm looking for.  You sit and play a few hands of bridge against one set of opponents.  Then you and the boards move and you play a few more hands of bridge against a new set of opponents.  Repeat until the end of the night (usually around 24 boards).  You don't necessarily play the boards in order.  For instance you may play 1-3, 7-9, 13-15, ..., and eventually 4-6.  Other people play them in a different order.

So now for the two sorting modes.  There's sort by board order (fairly easy to come up with an icon like the "1-24" I settled on) and there's sort by order played.

Which of these choices is appropriate?

```
A. A clock
B. A calendar
C. Something else
```

P.S. I remember reading an article a while back about how using a clock for this would be cause for rejection, but haven't been able to find it.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An hourglass(saves you from the clock metaphor) with a horizontal arrow, as time is more likely perceived as a horizontal flow.

Comment: I ended up trying this implementation but my icon looked horrible.  I had a different problem to solve that also wanted the same space so I decided to make the sort direction an intelligent global setting and removed the button entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I think a down arrow with a clock.

Comment: The down arrow certainly helps convey the sorting aspect.